# How to view Report into DevExpress using Flexcel in Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, devexpress

I am new in Devexpress. I now need to do report by using Flexcel technique.

My requirement include :

- Adding a datatable to Excel File and then view it into Report Screen so that users can print, export to any supported format (Ex: xls, pdf)​.
- I do not know how to use the "control" oF DevExpress to view Report using Flexcel yet.

This is my sample. It runs but the data cannot display. I use "documentViewer" to view:

```
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using FlexCel.Core;
using FlexCel.Report;
using FlexCel.XlsAdapter;

public partial class frmPrintSample : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public frmPrintSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.documentViewer1.DocumentSource= CreateReport(); 
        }
        public ExcelFile CreateReport()
        {
            FlexCelReport flexcelreport = new FlexCelReport();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //dt = GetfromToDataTable();

            flexcelreport.AddTable("Datatable", dt);
            ExcelFile rs = Run_templatereport(flexcelreport);

            return rs;
        }
        private ExcelFile Run_templatereport(FlexCelReport flexcelreport)
        {          
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            string filename = @"E:\Samplate.xlsx";

            if (!File.Exists(filename))
            {
                throw new Exception("Template Report is not exist!");
                return null;
            }
            ExcelFile result = new XlsFile(filename);
            flexcelreport.Run(result);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do not see any DevExpress code here... Does it work with the regular DataTable populated with some data?

Comment: I dont know hoW to use DevExpress to view Report from Excel File using Flexcel technique (input parameter is a datatable.). Give me how to use it.

Comment: Do you want to read an Excel file to a DataTable and then display a result?

Comment: I suggest that you contact DevExpress support directly to get guaranteed assistance. Once a solution is ready, please share it here to close the SO issue.